# Java security warning pop out

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5acqj.jpg) Currently I am facing an issue to handle the java security pop up using selenium when accessing my company intranet site. The pop out is due to loading of applet.

How to detect that the focus has been shifted to the pop out, So that I can use robot class to accept and run the applet.

The elements from the java security warning pop is not inspectable.

```
Browser: ie 11
Selenium version 3.14
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Comment: I have used sikuli, ui automation tool to accept the risk and run the application and then click on Run. However, is there any other ways this can be handled?